# with a rsa publickey string (not a file), when I encrypt, I got an error "invalid key format"

Tags: java, rsa, public-key-encryption

I've a public key string(get from an api), and i want to encrypt the parameter using the public key, while I get the error "java.security.InvalidKeyException: invalid key format", my code is as below:

```
try {
            KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
            X509EncodedKeySpec publicKeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(publicKey.getBytes());
            PublicKey key = keyFactory.generatePublic(publicKeySpec);
            params = EncryptionUtil.encrypt(params.getBytes(), key);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage());
        }

        logger.info("encrypt params:" + params);
```

the publicKey value is: "MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDBYu61cljDpI+XdWPO1bi5Ricv5+U/4u9Mqj4SdWp8YnCr3FaXTphW5mJol9KdqzK50GmD0Kv1x4z5gz6TDayfn527FX9KEO/puFlPiIkik2lg5UP9vGIyeWKoaxw1S8skjW13Md+Lw4i9ZqeoI9boLVMJdxMCtS+MTVDNxwDShwIDAQAB"

so, how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to decode you public key from api:

```
String pubk = "MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDBYu61cljDpI+XdWPO1bi5Ricv5+U/4u9Mqj4SdWp8YnCr3FaXTphW5mJol9KdqzK50GmD0Kv1x4z5gz6TDayfn527FX9KEO/puFlPiIkik2lg5UP9vGIyeWKoaxw1S8skjW13Md+Lw4i9ZqeoI9boLVMJdxMCtS+MTVDNxwDShwIDAQAB";
byte[] bPubk = Base64.getDecoder().decode(pubk);

try {
    KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    X509EncodedKeySpec publicKeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(bPubk);
    PublicKey key = kf.generatePublic(publicKeySpec);
    System.out.println(key);
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

Give this result:

```
Sun RSA public key, 1024 bits
  modulus: 135800586859931582642310957384205018809539137294767840577881254803756232956639555134422701591513823339589448014996895987307431572469047529249728795673095119495397484042215360480856267006156705758125294683622900407564820516858390483599968159314547137229473538993288665937138465454319026029781283370049170625159
  public exponent: 65537
```